# How do I get values from a hidden worksheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub ErrorCodeForMyTimeSheet()
    Worksheets("DataValues").Range("A2:A20")
End Sub
```

I want to loop thru the values and check to see if a Worksheet by the name exists.

How do I loop thru the values in A2 to A20?

Comment: You need to elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve. Where is the 'name' youre searching for? Also, be sure to qualify your `Worksheets` reference. We can help you if you encounter an issue where you can't solve a problem, but a simple loop is very well documented on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: I just don't know how to loop thru my range.

Comment: Google it. I can guarantee this has been asked before.

Comment: do a search for "how to loop through excel range".  you should have asked that in your question .... not "how do i get values from ....."

Comment: ^^ but add "site:stackoverflow.com excel vba" in front (i.e. google `site:stackoverflow.com excel vba how to loop through excel range`) to ensure you get the high quality results!  ;)

Comment: I saw dozens of pages and tried a dozen "solutions" and i get errors and spent hours trying to debug each solution. Obviously my setup has something different than the ones in the "google search"

Comment: If you edit your question to show what you tried, and explain why it didn't do what you wanted, people may be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment you want to loop through your range then try the below.
This is just a for loop in VBA

```
 sub testcode()
        dim i as double
    dim yournametofind as string
        for i = 2 to 20
        yournametofind  = Worksheets("DataValues").Range("A" & i).value
    if yournametofind = yournametofind then

    'do your things
    else

    do your things
    end if
        next i


        end sub
```